# Material-UI datepicker invalid date format issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker, material-ui, date-fns

I'm using the following Material-UI datepicker library:

```
import React from 'react'
import { MuiPickersUtilsProvider, KeyboardDatePicker } from "@material-ui/pickers";
import DateFnsUtils from "@date-io/date-fns";
import moment from 'moment';

    export default function DatePicker(props) {
    
        const { name, label, value, onChange } = props
    
    
        const convertToDefEventPara = (name, value) => ({
            target: {
                name, value
            }
        })
    
        return (
            <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
                <KeyboardDatePicker disableToolbar variant="inline" inputVariant="outlined"
                    label={label}
                    format="dd/MM/yyyy"
                    placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY"
                    name={name}
                    value={value}
                    onChange={date =>onChange(convertToDefEventPara(name,date))}                
    
                />
            </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
        )
    }
```

Here is the `handleInputChange` implementation that exists within `useFrom` that I am using within my below component where I'm using `DatePicker`

```
    import React, { useState } from 'react'
    import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core";
    
        export function useForm(initialFValues, validateOnChange = false, validate) {
        
        
            const [values, setValues] = useState(initialFValues);
            const [errors, setErrors] = useState({});
        
            const handleInputChange = e => {
                const { name, value } = e.target
                setValues({
                    ...values,
                    [name]: value
                })
                if (validateOnChange)
                    validate({ [name]: value })
            }
        
            const resetForm = () => {
                setValues(initialFValues);
                setErrors({})
            }
        
        
            return {
                values,
                setValues,
                errors,
                setErrors,
                handleInputChange,
                resetForm
        
            }
        }


const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    root: {
        '& .MuiFormControl-root': {
            width: '80%',
            margin: theme.spacing(1)
        }
    }
}))

export function Form(props) {

    const classes = useStyles();
    const { children, ...other } = props;
    return (
        <form className={classes.root} autoComplete="off" {...other}>
            {props.children}
        </form>
    )
}
```

Within my actual component, I am using the `DatePicker` as follows:

```
              <DatePicker
                    name="last_changed"
                    label="Date last changed"                        
                    value={values.last_changed}                        
                    onChange={handleInputChange}
              />
```

My problem is, when I load the `last_changed` date into state which has the value of "19/10/2021" back into this "Date last changed" field, I am receiving the error "Invalid date format" and don't understand why as I initially created this date, from this datepicker.

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Hello ArthurJ, can i see the handleInputChange implementation?

Comment: @Jayffe - I have included `handleInputChange` implementation

Comment: it seems to work, maybe the problem is somewhere else : https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-cache-wlwpx?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @Jayffe - the value is from a report that is getting loaded into the form, which causes the invalid date format. When console logging the date from the `DatePicker` component props, I get the value: `Tue Oct 19 2021 20:16:18 GMT+1100` - could this be causing my issue?

Comment: maybe we get somewhere, what is the console log of the value from the report ?

Comment: `Date last changed: "19/10/2021"`

Comment: try to change this format before sending it to the component like new Date('2021-10-19').toString()

Comment: @Jayffe - seems like if I hardcode the date `Tue Oct 19 2021 20:16:18 GMT+1100` in my `DatePicker` value, i.e.: `value={"Tue Oct 19 2021 20:31:29 GMT+1100 (Australian Eastern Daylight Time)"}` it works. Based on this, how can I convert `"19/10/2021"'` to `Tue Oct 19 2021 20:16:18 GMT+1100` ?

Comment: maybe something like this "19/10/2021".split('/').reverse().join('-')

Comment: did it solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert your date to js date string before sending it to your material-ui component by using Date toString() eventually

If you receive your date in that format '19/10/2021'
maybe you can do this

```
const receivedDate = '19/10/2019';
const formatedDate = receivedDate.split('/').reverse().join('-');

const textDate = new Date(formatedDate).toString()
```

Comment: This solved my problem. Really appreciate your assistance.